# Can't access https despite port 443 is opened

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl, port-443

This is my first time setting up a server and I've just installed a SSL cert. I have also made some changes to the iptable to allow access to 443. Below is the output of **iptables -L**

```
target     prot opt source         destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere       anywhere        state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere       anywhere        state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere       anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere       anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere       anywhere        state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere       anywhere        state NEW tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere       anywhere        state NEW udp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere       anywhere        tcp dpt:urd
REJECT     all  --  anywhere       anywhere        reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere       anywhere        state NEW tcp dpt:https
```

I also checked nmap by ssh'ing into the server and run nmap from the server itself.

```
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-15 15:31 SGT
Nmap scan report for <my.domain.ip>
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3005/tcp open  deslogin
3031/tcp open  epic
```

When I tried telnet [my.domain.ip] 443 remotely

```
Trying <my.domain.ip>...
telnet: connect to address <my.domain.ip>: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Lastly, I do not know if nginx.conf plays a part but below is a snippet of the code for the ssl for the domain

```
#include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen          <my.domain.ip>:80;
    server_name     mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    index           index.html index.htm index.py;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/mydomain.log.error;
    root            /home/fr/;
    charset         utf-8;

    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
    #location = /custom_50x.html {
    #        internal;
    #}

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  <my.domain.ip>:3031;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static {
        root        /home/fr/env/FRuler/fruler/;
    }
}

### for ssl  ###
server {
    listen          <my.domain.ip>:80;
    server_name     mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    index           index.html index.htm index.py;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/mydomain.log.error;
    root            /home/fr/;
    charset         utf-8;


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  <my.domain.ip>:3031;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static {
        root        /home/fr/env/FRuler/fruler/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name     mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mydomain/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mydomain/server.key;
    server_name mydomain www.mydomain.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/mydomain.log.error;
    location / {
        root /home/fr/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
### end of ssl ###
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just for completeness, where did you run `nmap` and `telnet` from? My guess would be `nmap` from the server itself but `telnet` from a remote host, can you confirm?

Comment: @jcaron yes, that is correct. I run nmap from the server itself and telnet from remotely, I've made the necessary changes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Order matters in iptables, rules are traversed sequentially.

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere       anywhere        reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere       anywhere        state NEW tcp dpt:https
```

After rejecting everything the subsequent rule opening port 443 for HTTPS will never be reached and have no effect. Your general reject rule should be last.

Comment: How come that nmap shows that the port is open???

Comment: Because port is open, it is just unreachable.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I assume that Gino ran `nmap` from the server itself, rather than from a remote host